# MySQL insert nested array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, nested

I am trying to insert this nested array to my database with PHP/MySQL:

```
[type] => Array
    (
     [0] => ready-made
     [1] => ready-made
     )

[company_name] => Array
    (
     [0] => Nevim
     [1] => sadasdsa
    )

[ico] => Array
    (
     [0] => 55
     [1] => 545
    )
```

Where first keys(type,etc.) are columns and second keys(numbers) are rows.
 But i am not able to discover the easiet or even any way ho to insert into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have made a connection to the database and in this example code I have used `$mysqli` as the variable holding the connection.

All you need to do is loop over one of the array of arrays, lets use `type` and then use the index of the current type array to reference the correct occurance of the other 2 arrays like this.

```
$data = [
    'type' => ['ready-made', 'ready-made'],
    'company_name' => ['Nevim', 'sadasdsa'],
    'ico' => [55, 545]

];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (type, company_name,ico) VALUES(?,?,?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
foreach ($data['type'] as $idx => $type) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', 
                        $type,
                        $data['company_name'][$idx],
                        $data['ico'][$idx]
                    );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

> I used the MYSQLI_ API here, but if you are using PDO tell me in a comment and I will add that as well
>
> You probably should also check that the 3 arrays are all the same length, as if one is shorter than the others you will get issues.

If you are using PDO

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (type, company_name,ico) VALUES(?,?,?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($data['type'] as $idx => $type) {
    $params = [$type, $data['company_name'][$idx], $data['ico'][$idx]];
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `foreach` to loop through the array and insert it

```
foreach($type as $key=>$value) {
    $sql = "insert into table (type,company_name,ico) values('$value','company_name[$key]','ico[$key]')"

}
```

Comment: This would be wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's